# Prove that if $ A \subset U $ is a set then $\overline{A} $ is closed.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

Edit: As pointed out in a comment and in an answer, we're talking about a metric space with distance $d$, $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ and $U$ is a universe.

---

I'm required to write the proof for:

> Prove that if $ A \subset U $ is a set then $\overline{A} $ is closed.

What I came up is this:

> Assume $A \subset U $.
>
> WTS: $\overline{A}$ is closed. $\overline{A}$ is closed if its
>   complementary $(\overline{A} ) \, ^ C$ is open.
>
> Take any $x \in (\overline{A} ) \, ^ C $.
>
> Recall $ \overline{A} \equiv \{y\in U | \forall \epsilon > 0,
> > B_{\epsilon}(y) \cap A\neq \varnothing \}. $
>
> Note that $B_{\epsilon}(y) \cap A \neq \varnothing \iff B_{\epsilon}(y) \not\subset A ^C $.
>
> Then we can write $ \overline{A} \equiv \{y\in U | \forall \epsilon > 0,
>  B_{\epsilon}(y) \not\subset (\overline{A} )^C \}. $
>
> So, $x \in (\overline{A} )^C \iff x \notin \overline{A} \iff  \neg \, \{x\in U | \forall \epsilon > 0, B_{\epsilon}(x) \not\subset A^C \} \iff $
>
> $x\in U s.t. \exists \epsilon > 0, B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset A^C.  $

Then I'm stuck, because I actually needed to get to $x\in U s.t. \exists \epsilon > 0, B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset (\overline{A})^C.  $
I've probably made some mistake or I miss something obvious on how to go on. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not much context. What is $U$? What does $\overline A$ mean? What does "closed" mean? I know what they would mean in a metric space, or a topological space, but I don't see anything like that in the problem.

Comment: I've posted the original problem as it was. I would say that we're talking metric spaces. @bof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m assuming $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ and $U$ establishes some sort of universe.  I’m also assuming we’re talking about a metric space with metric $d$.

If $y \notin \overline{A}$, then by definition $ \exists \epsilon \gt 0$ with $B(y, \epsilon) \cap A = \emptyset$.  Let $d(y, z)= \gamma \lt \epsilon$.  Let $\delta=(\epsilon-\gamma)/2$.  Then by the triangle inequality, $B(z, \delta) \subseteq B(y, \epsilon)$, so $\forall~z\in B(y, \epsilon), z \notin \overline{A}$ and $B(y, \epsilon) \cap \overline{A} = \emptyset$.

There’s a more general definition of closure that doesn’t rely on the use of a metric and that makes the proof easier.  You can define the closure of a set (in a given topology) as the intersection of all closed sets containing that set.

Comment: Thanks. This is a similar answer to the one in the solution sheet we're provided. I was wondering if the way I was going could be fruitfully pursued to the end? Have you any suggestions?

Comment: The construction in my answer shows (using the triangle inequality) that$B_{\epsilon}(y) \subseteq \overline{A}^c$.  So your proof will work, and that observation is how you finish it.